# Interlacing background images using jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut()

Tags: jquery

I use the following function to make a slideshow of images with fade in and out effects.

```
var project_photos = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
var project_photo_index = 0;

function nextPhoto() {
  $('#background').fadeOut();
  $('#background').css('background-image', 
    "url('images/" + project_photos[project_photo_index] + "')");
  $('#background').fadeIn();
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    if (project_photo_index+1 > project_photos.length) {
      project_photo_index = 0;
    } else {
      project_photo_index++;
    }
    nextPhoto();
  }, 5000);
}
```

However, I want to tweak the function a bit to remove the white moments in between `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`. What I want to achieve is:

*assuming the fade in and out time is 400ms, and the display time of each image is 5s*

1. Image 1 shows on-screen for 0 to 5s, starts fading out from 5 to 5.4s
2. Image 2 hides at first, start fading in from 4.8s to 5.2s (in order to fill the white gap between fade in and out), holds from 5.2 to 10.2s, then starts fading out from 10.2 to 10.6s
3. Image 3 hides at first, start fading in from 10.4s to 10.8s, holds from 10.8s to 15.8s, then starts fading out from 15.8s to 16.2s
4. (and Image 1 comes back with similar logic, loops forever until the timer has cleared)

How can I adjust the code to make this working as described?

Comment: can you edit http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HcfyD/1/ to recreate the case

Comment: also there is a bug in the use of setInterval - it should be setTimeout

Comment: the blank space could be because of the loading time for the image.... you preloading to fix it

Comment: changed the `setTimeout()` and added back `fadeOut()`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HcfyD/4/

Comment: @ArunPJohny this looks good. You should put it in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owiqIxA/5/edit)***

If you use 2 DIV elements you can fade the inner one:

```
<div id="bg2"><div id="bg1"></div></div>
```

than this is all you need:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
    n = images.length,
    c = 0,
    $1 = $('#bg1'),
    $2 = $('#bg2');

$.fn.setBG = function(){
  return this.css({backgroundImage: "url(images/"+ images[c] +")"});
};

(function loop(){
  $1.setBG().fadeTo(0,1).delay(2000).fadeTo(1000, 0, loop);
  c = ++c%n;
  $2.setBG();
})();
```

How this works:

```
#bg1:      set1 -- fadeOut -- set2 -- fadeOut -- set3 -- fadeOut -- set1 - ...
#bg2:      - set2 ------------- set3 ------------- set1 ------------- set2 ...
```

Comment: how to stop the `loop()` in case I want to stop/pause the effect?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor than you can do it like http://jsbin.com/owiqIxA/6/edit using setInterval

Comment: @ShivanRaptor or like this using almost the same code but setting a hover flag : http://jsbin.com/owiqIxA/7/edit

Comment: @ShivanRaptor better with setinterval. The other one is not that accurate on mouseenter.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var project_photos = ['//placehold.it/128/ff0000', '//placehold.it/128/ffff00', '//placehold.it/128/00ff00', '//placehold.it/128/00ffff'];
var project_photo_index = 0;

//preload the images
$.each(project_photos, function (i, src) {
    var img = $('<img />', {
        src: src
    })
})

function nextPhoto() {
    $('#background').fadeTo('normal', .5, function () {
        $(this).css('background-image', "url('" + project_photos[project_photo_index] + "')")
        $(this).fadeTo('normal', 1)
    });

    project_photo_index++;
    project_photo_index = project_photo_index < project_photos.length ? project_photo_index : 0;

    setTimeout(nextPhoto, 5000)
}

nextPhoto();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HcfyD/)